# Are the gerund forms 'having been + adj./noun..,There being,There having been,etc.' in use?

Tags: gerunds

Are these  **gerund forms**  correct / in use?

1. John's **having been** late..
2. **There being** people at the hotel..
3. **There having been** people at the hotel..
4. People **having had** cars..

I have no idea how to use these forms in sentences.That's why I couldn't provide perfect examples.(sorry for that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your examples are all grammatically sound gerund clauses. They may be employed in a variety of ways:

> *As a Subject NP*: John's having been late caused us many problems.
>   *As an Object NP*: The owners enjoy there being people at the hotel.
>   *As a 'supplemental' Absolute Clause*: There having been people at the hotel, the owners suffered no loss.
>   *As the object of a preposition*: The taxi drivers were greatly annoyed at people having had cars.

Your last example can also be interpreted as a noun plus a modifying participle phrase:

> People having had cars were invited to post photographs of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! and I have small problem.When we use a subject before the gerund ,Does it sound unnatural?  (e.g:1.people being searched by customs officers is unpleasant. 2.People having found money was a good thing..3.Cigarettes being smoked are bad for your health)

Comment: @Dinusha Not at all, BUT: **1)** there are different 'feels' in  subjects expressed as genitives (*their/people's being searched*) and as accusatives (*them/people being searched*). **2)** 'Generic' subjects like *people* are unnecessary: "Being searched ... is unpleasant" doesn't need a subject. **3)** Don't use perfect gerunds without a strong reason. **4)** Be careful with passives; your 3 is very awkward and would ordinarily be expressed as *Smoking cigarettes ...*, with *you* as the implied subject.

Comment: If I would use a subject before a passive gerund,Must it be 'genitive' or 'accusative'?

Comment: @Dinusha Yes; but in English the accusative (objective) is distinguished only in some personal pronouns (*me, him, her, us, them*); with all other subjects the accusative is the same as the uninflected form.